# could someone please double check my understanding of 2 forms that represent Machine Learning model?

Tags: terminology

This [CMU Machine Learning Text Book](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/mlbook/Joint_MLE_MAP.pdf) says

> when we are interested in learning some target function $f : X → Y$, we can more generally learn the probabilistic function $P(Y|X)$.

there are 2 forms above to represent a Machine Learning model.

is reasonable to say [kNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) is an example of this form

$f : X → Y$

while SVM is an example of another form

$P(Y|X)$

could someone please double check my understanding about these 2 forms?

Answer (score 0):

$P(Y|X)$ is a conditional probability representation where Y can be any output given input X. kNN can also be represented in this form please check this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/157509/264775)!. SVM can also be represented similarly.

$f:X\to Y$ denotes a function mapping between input X and output Y. which means there is a function that maps X to Y and our aim in the machine learning or statistical problem is to learn this function.