# Intuition behind kernel density estimation in Bishop 2006

Tags: nonparametric, kernel-smoothing, intuition

I have been wondering about this passage from Bishop **2.5.1 Kernel density estimators** (p. 122). The passage follows an explanation of how a density function $p$ could be approximated, based on the following argument:

1. Let random variable $X \sim p$. Consider a small region $R$ such that $x \in R$ for some $x \in X$. Let $P = P(X \in R) = \int_R p(x) \:\mathrm{d}x$.
2. Assume we have a data set with $N$ samples drawn from $p$. Then $K$, the number of samples that land inside $R$, is binomially distributed $K \sim Bin(N, P)$.
3. If $N$ is large, the variance of r.v. $K/N$ is close to zero, and so we expect $K/N$, the ML estimator for $P$, to give a good estimate for $P$.
4. Assume that $R$ is so small that $p$ is constant over $R$. Then $P \approx p(x)V$, where $V$ is the volume of $R$.
5. Thus, the approximation $p(x) = \frac{K}{NV}$ (2.246)

> Note that the validity of (2.246) depends on two contradictory
>   assumptions, namely that the region R be sufficiently small that the
>   density is approximately constant over the region and yet sufficiently
>   large (in relation to the value of that density) that the number K of
>   points falling inside the region is sufficient for the binomial
>   distribution to be sharply peaked.

Bishop, Christopher M. *Pattern recognition and machine learning*. Springer, 2006.

I am not sure I understand the second assumption.

Comment: Does this help https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244012/can-you-explain-parzen-window-kernel-density-estimation-in-laymans-terms/244023#244023 ?

Answer (score 1):

The canonical example for the binomial distribution is the coin toss. We can reduce the second point to the case of tossing a coin N times and getting K faces.

Getting a face after a coin toss is equivalent to sampling a data point, and that data point belonging to the region R (one implicit assumption in your question is that those R's are disjoint, and that $\cup_{i} R_{i}$ covers the sample space).

In this answer [Is KNN a discriminative learning algorithm?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105979/is-knn-a-discriminative-learning-algorithm/106081#106081) (shameless self-citation, sorry!), this idea is discussed in a bit more detail.