# kernel density estimation for more than one attribute

Tags: kernel-smoothing

Consider the Iris dataset, which has 4 attributes. KDE(kernel density estimation) is univariate analysis then how can we get overall kernel density estimation of the iris dataset

Answer (score 2):

With multivariate data, you need to use [multivariate kernel density estimation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244509/what-is-the-issue-in-my-calculation-of-multivariate-kernel-estimation/244654#244654), that differs from univariate case by either using [product of univariate kernels](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/358151/bandwidth-parameters-in-multivariate-kde-using-scipy-stats-gaussian-kde/358177#358177), or multivariate kernels (e.g. instead of univariate Gaussian, multivariate normal density as kernel).

Comment: That's surely right in principle. In practice, good luck visualizing a surface over all the variables based on just 150 observations for the _Iris_ data. I would focus on univariate and bivariate density estimation at most.

Comment: @NickCox it doesn’t say that the point is plotting it, otherwise agree.

Comment: A density estimate for any other purpose could be useful, but at the same time it would hard to know how far to trust it if you can't see it. I wouldn't trust a univariate estimate I couldn't see.