# Generate random draws from Kernel Density in Python

Tags: python, random-generation, kernel-smoothing

I reasoned a bit on where to post this question if stats, quant or stack. I will post it here because it is merely a statistical problem.

I have a vector `x` of numbers in Python (you might also imagine for simplicity that is normal) I simulate its Kernel density starting from this vector:

```
import scikits.statsmodels.api as sm
kde = sm.nonparametric.KDEUnivariate(x)
kde.fit()
```

Now if I want to extract a random matrix (10000x100) from this distribution how could I do?

Should I use `kde.score_sample`? If yes, I cannot manage to do this extraction.

Comment: What do you mean by "extracting matrix"? Do you mean drawing random samples from KDE?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 2):

[Kernel density](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244012/can-you-explain-parzen-window-kernel-density-estimation-in-laymans-terms/244023#244023) may be thought as a equally-weighted (with weights $\tfrac{1}{nh}$) [mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) of kernels $K$ centered at datapoints $y_i$

$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{nh} K\left(\frac{x - y_i}{h}\right)
$$

To draw samples from univariate kernel density, the following procedure can be applied (Silverman, 1986):

*Step 1.* Sample $i$ uniformly with replacement from $1,\dots,n$.

*Step 2.* Generate $\varepsilon$ to have probability density $K$.

*Step 3.* Set $x = y_i + h\varepsilon$.

If samples are required to have the same variance as your data, the procedure is modified as following:

*Step 3'.*

$$
x = \bar y + (y_i - \bar y + h\varepsilon)/(1 + h^2 \sigma^2_K/\sigma^2_Y)^{1/2}
$$

where $\sigma_K^2$ is variance of the kernel, while $\bar y$ and $\sigma_Y^2$ are variance and mean of $y$. If you are using Gaussian kernel, then to generate random draws from it you basically need only to be able to draw samples from standard normal distribution (for $\varepsilon$) and from discrete uniform distribution (for $i$'s).

The procedure can be easily extended for multivariate kernel densities, where instead of drawing single $y_i$ values, you draw whole rows of the $Y$ matrix.

To learn more you can check the documentation of [kernelboot](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=kernelboot) package for R (disclaimer: I'm the author) that goes into more details and provides multiple references on this subject.

---

Silverman, B. W. (1986). Density estimation for statistics and data analysis.
Chapman and Hall/CRC.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply benefit of the `.icdf()` method that take random numbers from the interval $[0,1)$ as input. This way, you can sample as many samples as you want.