# Generate random values from a distribution with a certain range?

Tags: distributions, simulation

I am interested in simulated values that follow a certain distributional shape and map them on to values of a certain range.

Here is an example with the beta distribution.

```r
rbeta(1000, 2, 1) |> 
  qunif(min = 10, max = 100) |> 
  hist()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I use the beta distribution to generate a distribution of probabilities of a certain shape then map those with the uniform quantile function into the value range I want in this case 10 to 100.

How would I do this with other distributions for example normal or weibull?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the [probability integral transform](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=probability+integral+transform+PIT)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- First of all, using the "inverse uniform function" to transform the data is a strange way of saying that you are scaling it. Yes, it does the job, but you are not using it to do anything related to uniform distribution but to scale $x' \in [0, 1]$  to $x \in [a, b]$ by using a linear transformation $x = x' \times (b - a) + a$, which is the inverse of scaling to unit range $x' = (x - a) \big/ (b - a)$. You can use this transformation to transform any *bounded* random variable.
- [Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) is unbounded, it ranges from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, and [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) from $0$ to $\infty$. You cannot "squeeze" an infinite range into the finite one like this. You would need [truncated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution) variants of those distributions to scale them. Alternatively, you could use something like [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) to scale the variables into $[0, 1]$ and then use the scaling you described, but this would not preserve the initial shape of the distribution anymore.
- But if you want to generate samples of distributions of arbitrary shape, you could instead just use [kernel densities](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244012/can-you-explain-parzen-window-kernel-density-estimation-in-laymans-terms/244023#244023) to approximate arbitrary distributions and [sample from them](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/286498/generate-random-draws-from-kernel-density-in-python/286557#286557).