# Kernel density estimation as a density

Tags: distributions, density-function, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

I have some troble understanding the Kernel density estimation.

If a consider the next example:

```
s<-0
z<-density(rnorm(25))
f<-function(i)approx(z$x,z$y,xout=i)$y
for(i in seq(min(z$x),max(z$x),length.out = 10000))
s<-s+f(i)
s
```

I expected getting that s is approximately equals to one since I am considering an approximation for the integral of the Kernel density function (that I suppose is also a density). However, I don't get the expected result. Why it doesn's sum one?
 The idea behind this is that I wanted to use the Kernel as the density of my data points. I was interpolating to get my explicit function and use with other x values. Or do you know another way to get a density function estimated by fitting?

Comment: If you approximate an integral as a sum of rectangular areas, the *width* of the rectangle matters, not just its height.

Answer (score 1):

The [kernel density](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244012/can-you-explain-parzen-window-kernel-density-estimation-in-laymans-terms/244023#244023) works fine

```r
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(25)
z <- density(x)
f <- function(i) splinefun(z$x, z$y)(i)
integrate(f, min(z$x), max(z$x))
## 1.000833 with absolute error < 7.8e-05
```

The problem is that kernel density is a function of continuous variable, and sum is not the same as an [integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral). Integral can be approximated by a Riemann sum, e.g. using [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule)

$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\, dx \approx \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{N} \left( x_{k+1} - x_{k} \right) \Big( f(x_{k+1}) + f(x_{k}) \Big)
$$

but it's far from taking raw sum of $f(x_k)$. You cannot expect the sum to be equal to one even from the bare fact that [probability density can be greater then one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/can-a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-be-ok) and summing things that can be greater then one, obviously leads to the sum that can greater then one.