# How does this code find the CDF?

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

How does the below code give CDF?
Can someone please explain what
`np.arange(len(sorted_data))/float(len(sorted_data)-1)` does?

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('Filename.txt')

sorted_data = np.sort(data)

yvals=np.arange(len(sorted_data))/float(len(sorted_data)-1)

plt.plot(sorted_data,yvals)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted implements the [empirical cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function). We want to estimate unknown cumulative distribution function, $P(X \le x)$, from the data. The function applies the most basic definition of probability, based on counts

$$
P(\text{something}) = \frac{\text{how often something happen}}{\text{sample size}}
$$

In this case, we are are calculating cumulative probabilities, so it is

$$
P(X \le x) = \frac{\#(X \le x)}{N}
$$

where $\#$ is the count operator, that counts the values in $X$ meeting the condition.

The function however is *incorrect*, as it should be rather

```
yvals = np.arange(1, len(sorted_data)+1)/float(len(sorted_data))
```

because for the first element of `sorted_data` we don't want it to return probability equal to zero (obviously we *observed* this value, so it cannot happen with zero probability!).

But let's discuss it in more details. We are dealing with `sorted_data`, the data that is already sorted for us in ascending order. For each element in `sorted_data`, we assign some value from `yvals`. To calculate the values, we use the `np.arange(1, len(sorted_data)+1)` function, that returns series $1,2,\dots,N$. This series corresponds to empirical cumulative counts, since first value in `sorted_data` appeared only once, there was two values smaller or equal to the second value from `sorted_data`, all the values were smaller or equal then the last value from `sorted_data` etc. Next, the values are divided by `float(len(sorted_data))`, so by the sample size $N$ (the `float` function is needed only for python 2, for it to calculate the floating-point division rather then integer). So we end up with fractions $\tfrac{1}{N},\tfrac{2}{N},\dots,\tfrac{N}{N}$, that correspond to probabilities.

Notice that this assumes that we are dealing with *continuous* variable in here, as the function ignores the fact that there could be duplicated elements in `sorted_data`. If you are dealing with *discrete* variable, you should rather calculate this on counts of sorted values.

If you wonder if we could use similar function to calculate the non-cumulative probabilities, $P(X=x)$, then the answer is: yes, but only for *discrete* variable (and large sample size to get reasonable approximation). For *continuous* variable it gets more complicated, because there is infinitely many possible values of $X$, [so $P(X=x)=0$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142730/px-x-0-when-x-is-continuous-variable), and for this reason we have [probability densities](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/can-a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-be-ok), i.e. "probabilities per foot". What follows, for continuous variables we have [histograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram), [kernel density estimators](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244012/can-you-explain-parzen-window-kernel-density-estimation-in-laymans-terms/244023#244023) and a few other, less popular, estimators.

Answer (score 1):

When we learn a programming language, one of the skill that I think is crucial is to print your intermediate step for small cases.

Suppose your sorted_data is of length $5$

```
np.arange(len(sorted_data))
```

created the numpy array

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

We want to normalize these to uniformly separated points from $0$ to $1$. So we want to divide it by $4.0$ (notice the $.0$, it matters in programming language which data type are you using).

Hence for the example of an array of length $5$, you obtain the following.

```
array([0.  , 0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1.  ])
```

I will leave it as an exploratary task for you to figure out if it is really a cdf if your data array is something like $[1,2,3,4,5]$, $[1,4,5,8,9]$, and also $[1,2,2,2,5]$.

Comment: thanks for the response Mr.Goh.
`sorted_data = np.sort(data_bening.radius_mean)
y = np.arange(len(sorted_data))/float(len(sorted_data)-1)'

I was refering to a code on a kernel & he did a `np.arrange` on the length of `sorted_data` which is printing numbers from 1-356(got this, after printing out like you said). Shouldn't the CDF be calculated on `sorted_data`?

Comment: yes, the sorted data example that I included could be $[1,4,5,8,9]$. We plot the evenly spaced value in $[0,1]$ against the sorted data.